# Where Clause Applied To Multiple Patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, where-clause

I have a function with multiple patterns. I have two or more of them which share the same expression which I want to replace. Now if I write a `where` clause at the bottom, indent it and define a new variable as the expression I wanted to replace it won't work.

Example:

```
myFunction firstParam secondParam = expression
myFunction firstParam _ = 1 + expression
    where expression = firstParam + secondParam
```

Compiler message:

```
Not in scope: `expression'
Not in scope: `secondParam'
```

How do I do it?

Comment: In the code above, the second case will never be evaluated, since the first one catches anything, since `firstParam,secondParam` are two variables. What are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: Also, `where` expression applies only to the second case, so you do not have `secondParam` in its scope, and you do not have `expression` in the scope of first case.

Comment: @chi: I made up a random example to illustrate the question so the semantics didn't really matter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can factor out the pattern matches into a case. For example:

```
myFunction :: Int -> Int -> Int
myFunction a b = case (a, b) of
  (0, 4) -> x
  (_, b) -> x + b
  where
    x = a + b
```

Here `x` is visible in both case branches.