# scope: where for multiple polymorphic patterns

Tags: haskell

The accepted answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961795/where-clause-applied-to-multiple-patterns) shows how to use `case ... of` to utilize a `where` definition across multiple pattern-matches. Now in my case this doesn't seem to work (ghc complains: `Variable not in scope: x`).

```
data PolyTree a = PolyBranch a (PolyTree a) (PolyTree a) | PolyLeaf a

paths' :: PolyTree a -> [a] -> PolyTree [a]
paths' pt buf = case pt of
  (PolyLeaf x)           -> PolyLeaf buf'
  (PolyBranch x pt1 pt2) -> PolyBranch buf' (paths' pt1 buf') (paths' pt2 buf')
  where buf' = buf ++ [x]
```

Can I do this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `buf'` is defined in terms of `x`, which is bound by the inner `case` expression, whereas `where` is actually "outside" of the expression in the right hand side.

```
paths' pt buf =
  (case ... of ... -> ...(1) ; ... -> ...(2) )
  where ...(3)
```

`x` is only visible inside `(1)` and `(2)`, but not in `(3)`. The occurences of `x` in `(1)` and `(2)` should really be considered as two variables with the same name.

If you want `x` to be visible inside that `where` clause, it must be bound on the left of the `=` sign. One way to do this is to factor `x` out of the `PolyTree` type.

```
data PolyTree a = PolyTree a (PolyBranch a)
data PolyBranch a = PolyBranch (PolyTree a) (PolyTree a) | PolyLeaf

paths' (PolyTree x pt) buf = ...
  where buf' = buf ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Having both variables named `x` in scope at that point would require quite weird scoping (and alpha-conversion) rules.

Instead, you can handle each `x` separately.

```
paths' :: PolyTree a -> [a] -> PolyTree [a]
paths' pt buf = case pt of
  (PolyLeaf x)           -> let
     buf' = buf ++ [x]
     in PolyLeaf buf'
  (PolyBranch x pt1 pt2) -> let
     buf' = buf ++ [x]
     in PolyBranch buf' (paths' pt1 buf') (paths' pt2 buf')
```

It could be a good idea to remove the `case` and using multiple defining equations, instead. You would still need to duplicate the `where`.

```
paths' (PolyLeaf x) buf = PolyLeaf buf'
   where buf' = buf ++ [x]
paths' (PolyBranch x pt1 pt2) buf = PolyBranch buf' (paths' pt1 buf') (paths' pt2 buf')
   where buf' = buf ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already explain the reason, but here are two more alternative ways to write it which I would prefer to their suggestions:

```
paths' :: PolyTree a -> [a] -> PolyTree [a]
paths' pt buf = case pt of
  (PolyLeaf x)           -> PolyLeaf (addBuf x)
  (PolyBranch x pt1 pt2) -> 
    let buf' = addBuf x in
    PolyBranch buf' (paths' pt1 buf') (paths' pt2 buf')
  where addBuf x = buf ++ [x]

paths' :: PolyTree a -> [a] -> PolyTree [a]
paths' pt buf = case pt of
  (PolyLeaf x)           -> PolyLeaf buf'
  (PolyBranch x pt1 pt2) -> PolyBranch buf' (paths' pt1 buf') (paths' pt2 buf')
  where buf' = buf ++ [getX pt]
        getX (PolyLeaf x) = x
        getX (PolyBranch x pt1 pt2) = x
```