# Apply function to argument before performing pattern matching

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and trying to not instinctively think imperatively. I have a function which does all the work in a pattern matching block, however it needs to pattern match on the argument *after* a function is applied to it.

Doing this in a functional way gets me to this:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = bar $ show n

bar :: String -> String
bar [] = ""
bar (c:s) = "-" ++ bar s
```

Where `foo` is the function I'm trying to implement but `bar` is where all the work gets done. `foo` only exists to provide the right type signature and perform the precursor `show` transformation before calling `bar`. In practice, `bar` could get quite complicated, but still, I have no reason to expose it as a separate function.

What's the Haskell way to perform a simple function like `show` and "then" pattern match on the result of that?

I tried changing the pattern matching to a `case` statement, but it didn't permit the all-important recursion, because there was no function to call recursively. For the same reason, using a [where clause applied to multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961795/where-clause-applied-to-multiple-patterns) also doesn't work.

Comment: Note that this is an example of composition, as `foo` could be defined simply as `foo = bar . show`.

Comment: Breaking things up into multiple functions is perfectly normal; even in imperative programming it's usually recommended to keep procedures/methods small, breaking up complicated functionality into multiple units. And just like in most imperative languages, you don't have to expose all of the functions you have written; the module system is perfectly capable of exporting `foo` and keeping `bar` private. However the answer you found with `where` is a great way of making it completely clear that `bar` is only written for the purpose of defining `foo`, and is irrelevant to any other purpose.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this is `foo n = '-' <$ show n` -- i.e. reuse existing recursive functions where possible rather than writing the recursion yourself.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can't you just do `foo n = case (show n) of... `?

Comment: @RobinZigmond nearly, but when you do the `(c:s)` case there is no `bar` to call recursively. If you try to call `foo` instead, you'll pass a `String` and it is expecting an `Int`.

Comment: I see. In that case I think a helper function, whether defined at the top-level (but not exported) or locally in a `where` (as shown in your answer) is a perfectly sensible and idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 4):

I remembered that [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where) often seemed to emphasise that `where` and `let` are more powerful than they first seem because "everything is a function" and the clauses are *expressions* themselves.

That prompted me to see if I could push `where` a bit harder and use it to essentially define the helper function `bar`. Turns out I can:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = bar $ show n
  where bar [] = ""
        bar (c:s) = "-" ++ bar s
```

Unless there's a better way, I think this is the solution I'm after. It took a bit of beating back my imperative tendencies to see this, but it's starting to look logical and much more "core" than I was imagining.

Please provide an alternative answer if these assumptions are leading me off course!

Comment: Aside: I’m not sure whether this limitation relates to the imperative/functional divide. Other functional languages (e.g. the ML family, and even [λ-calculus with sums](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4110/2012fa/lectures/lecture21.pdf) i.e. a theoretical prototype of functional languages) do pattern matching on arbitrary *expressions*, rather than on function parameters (you get essentially what you achieved in Haskell with your `where` construct, except that you don’t have to name the matcher).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether the pattern-matching function is recursive or not.
In your example, it is called `bar` and is recursive.

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = bar $ show n

bar :: String -> String
bar [] = ""
bar (c:s) = "-" ++ bar s
```

Here, the (arguably) best solution is the one you found: use `where` (or `let`) and define it locally to `foo`:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = bar $ show n
   where
   bar :: String -> String   -- optional type annotation
   bar [] = ""
   bar (c:s) = "-" ++ bar s
```

The type annotation for the inner function is optional. Many Haskellers think that the top-level function `foo` should have its signature (and GHC with `-Wall` warns if you do not provide it) but also believe that the inner function do not have to be annotated. For what it is worth, I like to add it when I think it's non obvious from the context. Feel free to include or omit it.

When `bar` is not recursive, we have other options. Consider this code:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = bar $ show n

bar :: String -> String
bar []    = "empty"
bar (c:s) = "nonempty " ++ c : s
```

Here, we can use `case of`:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = case show n of
   []    -> "empty"
   (c:s) -> "nonempty " ++ c : s
```

This calls function `show` first, and then pattern-matches its result. I think this is easier to read than adding a `where` to define `bar`.

Theoretically, speaking, we *could* follow the `case` approach even in the recursive case, and leverage `fix` (a function from the library) to close the recursion. I do *not* recommend you to do this, since defining `bar` using `where` (or `let`) is more readable. I'm adding this less readable option here only for the sake of completeness.

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo n = fix (\bar x -> case x of
   []    -> ""
   (c:s) -> "-" ++ bar s
   ) $ show n
```

This is equivalent to the first recursive code snippet, but it requires much more time to read. The helper `fix` has its uses, but if I read this in actual production code I'd think the programmer is trying to show they are "clever" instead of writing simple, readable code.